# How To Change Image in Array Based on Textbox input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, textbox

I'm trying to make my page so a user can type a number value between 1 and 200 to get to whichever image they want to view. I've played around with the code, but I can't seem to get anything to work. Below is my code that I've tried to do this with. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: New Code:

```
`
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body style="background-color: teal;">
<form>
<center>
<div width="50%" style="width: 50%;">
<div id="main" align="middle">
<img src="page1.jpg" alt="" id="mainImg" height="90%">
</div> 
<div id="imglist">
<a href="javascript:previousImage('mainImg')"><img src="previous.png" alt="" 
align="left"></a>
<input id="myid" name="myid" size="3" type="text"></input>
<a href="javascript:nextImage('mainImg')"><img src="next.png" alt="" align="right"></a>
<script>
var imgArray = new Array();

var imgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
imgs[i] = new Image();
imgs[i].src = "page" + (i + 1) + ".jpg";
}


function nextImage(element)
    {
    var img = document.getElementById(element);

    for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
    {
        if(imgArray[i].src == img.src) // << check this
        {
            if(i === imgArray.length){
                document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[0].src;
                break;
            }
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i+1].src;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function previousImage(element)
{
   var img = document.getElementById(element);

   for(var i = 0; i < imgArray.length;i++)
  {
      if(imgArray[i].src == img.src)
      {
         if(i === 0){
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[imgArray.length-1].src;
            break;
         }
         else{
            document.getElementById(element).src = imgArray[i-1].src;
            break;
         }
      }
   }
}

window.onload = function() {
   var elm = document.getElementById("myid"),
   var img = document.getElementById("mainImg");
   elm.onkeyup = function(event) {
      if (this.value) {
         var num = parseInt(this.value, 10);
             if (num >= 1 && num <= 200 {
            img.src = "page" + num + ".jpg";
         }
      }
   }
} 
</script>
</div>
</div>
</center>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (this.value.length === 1,2,3) {` Why do you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean for this:

```
if (this.value.length === 1,2,3) {
```

to be this:

```
if (this.value.length <= 3) {
```

In addition, I think you want to be converting the whole input value to a number, not using the individual keycodes.

I might suggest this different/simpler way of doing this that is much more [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) (don't repeat yourself):

```
// preload images
var imgs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    imgs[i] = new Image();
    imgs[i].src = "page" + (i + 1) + ".jpg"; 
}

window.onload = function() {
   var elm = document.getElementById("myid");
   var img = document.getElementById("mainImg");
   elm.onkeyup = function(event) {
      if (this.value) {
          var num = parseInt(this.value, 10);
          if (num >= 1 && num <= 200) {
              img.src = "page" + num + ".jpg";
          }
      }
   }
}
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4dqbP/

Summary of changes:

1. Preload images in a loop rather than copied code
2. Construct image names dynamically
3. Make `img` variable to a local variable rather than an implicit global with `var` in front of it
4. Check to see if the input field is empty
5. Use `parseInt()` to parse the value of the input field into a number
6. Range check the parsed number
7. If in valid range, then construct the image name using that number

Comment: Using your changes made the text box display, however the image will not change when a value is entered into the box; additionally, my buttons no longer worked. I'm going to update my code in the original question to reflect what it currently is.

Comment: @Elgo - I fixed a typo in my code and corrected it.  You can see my code work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/4dqbP/

Comment: Thanks, the box works now! How would I fix the issue with my buttons?
The code is in the original text for the previous/next.

Comment: @Elgo - You can see a version with next and previous here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/vsBFM/

Comment: Thank you so much, you were a huge help. I definitely couldn't have done it without you. When I get up to 15 rep, I'll come back and upvote this. Thanks again, and have a good one.

Comment: +1 for not only answering, but providing explanations and a better approach.